# How to generate column drop and create script in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can anybody tell me the way to generate drop and create script of column from sql server management studio? I did used generate change script option but it just generated create script and not drop script for the column.

Also, 
I could not find the way to add named default constraint or any other specific named constraint from table design view. It just adds a default constraint with dynamically generated name if I specify a default value.

Thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 4):

If you open a table of your choice in the visual designer in SSMS, and you drop a column, then create a new column, and before exiting or saving, you choose `Generate Change Script` from the context menu in the designer, you *should* get both operations in that change script:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Messages ADD
    IsActive bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Messages_IsActive DEFAULT 1
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Messages
    DROP COLUMN ToProfileId
GO
```

I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2 - not sure if something might have changed from previous versions. Important: do not save or leave the designer before getting your change script!

As far as I know, there's no provision in the visual designer to name a default constraint - as you can see from my example, however, the system default seem to be pretty useable - no?

If you really must use your own naming convention, there's no other way than editing your T-SQL script before you execute it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi marc_s,

Thanks for the reply. 

Actually what I wanted is to get drop and create script of the same new column I am adding. 

Also,
Yes you are right we can use sql servers naming but I don't know why sometimes it adds some dynamic numbers with constraint name something like this
DF__Leagues__AcceptO__68536ACF 
Those numbers I actually don't want.